# How to sort Dates in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, date, nssortdescriptor

In my app I am bookmarking the words in different days, I have the sorting options such as sort recent first and oldest first.  I am unable to sort the words according to the bookmarked date, How to do it? By using Descriptors my sorting is not fine as only the first two entries are getting sorted. My code is:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"cellType" ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"entrydate" ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil];

[self.favoriteEntries sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"descendingDate" forKey:@"BookmarkSortType"];
```

Comment: instead of localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare try @selector(compare:)

Comment: Is `entrydate` a `NSString` or `NSDate`?

Comment: It depends on your data.  `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` only applies to `NSString`.  If your app isn't crashing when you use that one, your dates are strings, and we can't help without knowing what format you use.

Comment: @Avi we are using it as strings how to overcome it

Comment: You should show us what those string representations of the dates look like. You probably want to use a `NSDateFormatter`, and then sort based upon the resulting `NSDate` objects, but the specifics will vary depending upon the format of your strings.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406067/separate-future-date-in-nsmutablearray/28406319#28406319 Maybe first you need to convert `NSString` to `NSDate` then compare date using `predicateWithBlock`

Comment: Mahalakshmi show us the string dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use bubble sort.It will give you exact result without any confusion.Yes , the line of codes are more than predefined function but it will be correct to use bubble sort.

Comment: What advantage does this give over the built-in sort classes?

Comment: Explain further. your answer is too vague. why is it better than other sorting option?

Answer (score -2):

Try like this:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];//SET_YOUR_DATE_FORMAT
          NSString *updatedDateStr1 = YOUR_FIRST_DATE_STRING;
          NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:updatedDateStr1];
          NSString *updatedDateStr2 = YOUR_SECOND_DATE_STRING;
          NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:updatedDateStr2];
     NSComparisonResult result = [date2 compare:date1];//THIS WILL RETURN ONE OF NSOrderedAscending , NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedDescending
```

Comment: No, store data using the correct data type, which in this case is `NSDate`.  Constantly converting `NSString` to `NSDate` in order to compare is very inefficient.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you have `NSString` Object. you need to convert it in `NSDate` object then compare using Predicate and sort as per your need. Modify `obj` whatever you have in your dictionary or array.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];// Whatever your current stringDate format.
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSPredicate *findFutureDates = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind){
    NSDate *dd = [df dateFromString:(NSString *)obj ];
    return ([[NSDate date] compare:dd] == NSOrderedAscending);
}];

NSArray *arrFutureDates = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: findFutureDates];
NSLog(@"%@",arrFutureDates);
```

Maybe this will help you.